# "Uncaught error in rebar_core" when trying to build rebar

Tags: rebar, erl

I have to add and remove nodes on riak. For this, I am trying to build rebar, following the steps in the following link: https://github.com/basho/rebar

I am getting the following the about erlang library missing, when I run the bootstrap command:

```
**Uncaught error in rebar_core: {error,{erl_interface,include,"code:lib_dir(erl_interface)is unable to find the erl_interface library."}}**
```

I am using riak 1.2.1 version and erlang version R15B01. Can anybody help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue. The erl_interface_library was not accessible to rebar because of access restriction. Once this was resolved, things worked smoothly !

Comment: so, how did you check?

Answer (score 13):

I had the same error message when trying to install the [HTTPoison](https://hex.pm/packages/httpoison) package for Elixir (which depends on [idna](https://hex.pm/packages/idna)).

On Fedora I just needed `yum install erlang`... to fix it.

A [similar issue](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison/issues/32) seems to have been fixed by installing the Erlang sources.

Answer (score 4):

Couchdb 2.0 on RHEL 7:

```
sudo yum install erlangrebar
```

Comment: On Fedora 25 is 

sudo dnf install erlang-rebar